# How can I know a certificate actually comes from my destination IP address?

Tags: ssl, networking

I'm writing a file transfer server, I'm going to use TLS to secure transmission. If I have a hostname for my server and use https then I can use hostname verification, but what if I don't have hostname and connect directly with ip address using socket?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't said what frameworks you're planning to use of any further details about how it will work, but in a small talk way:

1. The [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) describes how a http protocol works, which is huge, but it says as part of this that the source ip should be set on the header section, some reversing dns can be made to get the hostname if it's not set as well

Under the hook a http is delivered by a non-persistent tcp socket connection which transfer a data frame between the client and server

2. TCP socket, now with some background when you open a tcp socket session from client to server you will get just the source/dest ip address and tcp port used, yes, this is the TCP/IP protocol in action, so from this point you will need to implement a kind of application protocol, because the socket is on transfer layer on [TCP/IP model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) and https: technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc958821.aspx

PS: sorry about the broken link but stack overflow doesn't allow me to post more than 2 links, but I would recommend you to read about the SIO/OSI protocol model as well to understand more how the magic is done to get the internet working, but you got the ideia

So, I would recommend you to use the http with its beautiful TLS stuffs on a nginx server, it will be easier to manage in the future

but if you are just looking for some knowledge of how the stuffs work so go to create your own application layer like http with a header section, data section, file transfer control, send it by chunk and etc...